# How to produce usable callstack on ARM?

Tags: c++, arm, gdb, stack-unwinding

I develop C++ application on ARM (Raspberry Pi, g++ (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0
). When I try to debug my code or the application crashes in my code, I get the correct callstack without any problem. But when the application crashes in external library or I step into external library in GDB, the callstack is lost and it does not contain anything useful except the function call.

For example, when I break at the beginning of memcpy function, I get the following:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76fa4b5c in memcpy () at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
#1  0x000e6118 in CWatchDog::ComputeBatteryPercentage(float) (this=0x2643140, voltage=3.96600008) at WatchDog.cpp:197
#2  0x000e5c24 in CWatchDog::BatteryControl(CWatchDog::RxPacketData const&) (this=0x2643140, data=...) at WatchDog.cpp:149
... etc ...
```

but when I step a few lines, after the instruction "vpush", I get only the following:

```
(gdb) bt    
#0  0x76fa4b60 in memcpy () at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
#1  0x00000000 in  ()
```

Is there any posibility how to enable full call stacks in external functions?
I tried building my code with -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -mapcs-frame but it makes no difference.

Comment: are you using debug builds of the other libraries?

Comment: Why would you need to use debug builds of libraries, especially when talking about system libraries?
When debugging the same application built for Win32/x64, I can step and see whole callstack even in highly optimized release builts of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Those binaries would need to include a symbol table which shows where caller/callee values are.  They can be in a register or some place on the stack.  The information is rather large.  So, you have a design trade off.   A user who doesn't want a stack trace will have to pay the price for larger disk space.  For embedded situation, this may be flash or even RAM to enable the tracing.  For gdb (implying gcc/clang), this information is usually detached.  It can be loaded from a 'sym' (or symbol file).  It depends on your gcc release.  Also, as it is open source, you can rebuild and modify.

Comment: Some canned comparison to Windows in this context seems to show a little bit of ignorance.  Windows is like that because they will not ever give you the source, and it is an OS/software framework that is encouraging people to hide software.  So, for this context giving tracing in 'highly optimized release'  builds is the only possibility.  Open source is different because it does not need to make compromises.

Comment: I don't understand much why this should be related to open source. Even on Linux, I can have 3rd party proprietary library without source code and debugging symbols available. And I am not interested in knowing the source location in this library when debugging some problem in my application. What I just want is to step through the assembly in the debugger and get the backtrace when my application crashes. Now I only see that it crashed in external library but I am not able to find out that it is caused by passing invalid value from my code to this library.

Answer (score 1):

It is common on many architectures that you must have either full debug info or a frame pointer for backtracing to work. Sometimes the ABI mandates the use of a frame pointer (in addition to a stack pointer), sometimes not. On architectures with relatively few registers it is useful to optimize away the frame pointer so the register can be used for other things. You can typically prevent it doing this in your own binaries using `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, but that doesn't help you with prebuilt binaries. (On *some* architectures you must have frame pointers; debug info alone is not enough.)

Many Linux distributions provide additional debug packages to install alongside their library packages. These are often not installed by default in order to save disk space and reduce download sizes. GDB will look for the debug info files and use them if it can find them, but will not complain if it cannot.

Here is some information I found about [Raspbian debug packages](https://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages/28-raspbian-debug). I don't know if that's specifically what you need, but it shows they exist.